# Hype Machine Parse "dateloved" in JSON

Tags: json, parsing, datetime

Hi there I am trying to understand the format of the "dateloved" in the Hype Machine JSON. I have not been able to find any documentation on it on their site.

I had to like a song and record the time to figure out that:
1317920279 = 06/10/2011  12:57:00 PM

How would I parse these type of dates/times? Is it some sort of standard I should know about?

Here is an example JSON:
http://hypem.com/playlist/loved/aren55555/json/1/data.js

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time is actually the "number of milliseconds since epoch".

In ruby I parsed it by doing something like `Time.at(1317920279)` which returns the date/time in a Time object.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) to parse the date in javascript. 
The date is in seconds, not milliseconds.

See Unix Timestamp: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/

`var date = moment.unix(1360618442)`

Result: Mon Feb 11 2013 16:34:02 GMT-0500 (EST)